# Mixture usage of CPU and GPU in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am building a neural network on Keras, including multiple layers of LSTM, Permute and Dense.

It seems LSTM is GPU-unfriendly. So I did research and use

```
With tf.device('/cpu:0'):
   out = LSTM(cells)(inp)
```

But based on my understanding about `with`, `with` is `try...finally` block to ensure that clean-up code is executed. I don't know whether the following CPU/GPU mixture usage code works or not? Will they accelerate speed of training?

```
With tf.device('/cpu:0'):
  out = LSTM(cells)(inp)
With tf.device('/gpu:0'):
  out = Permute(some_shape)(out)
With tf.device('/cpu:0'):
  out = LSTM(cells)(out)
With tf.device('/gpu:0'):
  out = Dense(output_size)(out)
```

Comment: You're facing the same problem as I am ... but you won't need that for this example. Reshape layers are very very light, they do almost nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you may read [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py#L3324) - `tf.device` is a context manager which switches a default device to this passed as its argument in a context (block) created by it. So this code should run all `'/cpu:0'` device at `CPU` and rest on `GPU`.

The question will it speed up your training is really hard to answer because it depends on the machine you use - but I don't expect computations to be faster as each change of a device makes data to be copied between `GPU RAM` and machine `RAM`. This could even slow down your computations.

Comment: Yes. It WILL definitely speed up training. I made my model in two versions. The version CPU+GPU trains a batch in 30seconds. The version pure GPU took an unknown time bigger than my patience of a few minutes.

Comment: Could you provide a source code / notebook for comparision?

Comment: Create a regular convolutional model and stack a few LSTM layers at the end. Make one model use cpu for the LSTM layers. --- Update: the pure GPU model just blew up the GPU's memory.

Comment: I thought that you were talking about a model from this example. The process you are talking about is called a late fusion and there is a great paper from Karpathy about it.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a model using 2 LSTM and 1 dense layers and trained it in my GPU (NVidia GTX 10150Ti) Here is my observations.

1. use CUDA LSTM https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#cudnnlstm
2. Use a bath size which helps more GPU parallelism, if I use a very small batch size(2-10) GPU multi cores are not utilized; so I used 100 as batch size
3. If I train my network on GPU and try to use it for predictions on CPU, it works in-terms of compiling and running but the predictions are weird. In my case I have the luxury to use a GPU for prediction as well.
4. for multi layer LSTM, need to use

here is some sample snippet

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.cudnn_recurrent.CuDNNLSTM(neurons
                , batch_input_shape=(nbatch_size, reshapedX.shape[1], reshapedX.shape[2])
                , return_sequences=True
                , stateful=True))
```