# How do you specify that a specific Keras layer should be assigned to the CPU?

Tags: python, tensorflow, memory, keras, gpu

I am working on a sequence-to-sequence model, mostly following the tutorial [here](https://blog.keras.io/a-ten-minute-introduction-to-sequence-to-sequence-learning-in-keras.html).

One of the layers on my model is too big to fit into GPU memory, but I would still like to be able to use the GPU for the other layers. Is it possible to move just that layer in Keras?

I tried doing this:

```
with tf.device('/device:CPU:0'):
  decoder_outputs = Dense(num_decoder_tokens, activation='softmax')(x)
```

but it does not seem to work. I still run out of memory.

This seems to work:

```
with tf.device('/device:CPU:0'):
  model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs_dense)
  model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy')
```

but it moves the entire model to the CPU, and the training time jumps up to a few thousand hours, so I cannot do that.

I guess it's possible in Tensorflow/pyTorch, but I was wondering if there was a way to do it while using Keras.

EDIT:
There is another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46371605/3138875) that sort of talks about the same problem, but the accepted answer there does not seem to work on Keras and I do not have enough reputation to comment on the answer :(

EDIT2:
The above [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46371605/3138875) *does* solve the problem. It did not seem to work in my case initially, but that was because I was using a Jupyter notebook and probably forgot to execute the cell after editing or something similar.

Comment: Are you sure this is the only layer that occupies too much memory? Try reducing your batch size.  As far as I remember, I also used that same answer you mentioned without problems.

Comment: Did you use it with Keras?

Comment: Yes, I only use keras.

Comment: It seems to work now. I was using a Jupyter notebook though. So I guess it could have been me forgetting to re-execute some cell after editing it. Do you know of some way in Keras/TF to see which device a tensor is assigned to?